# Unable to upload the .ipa file to Test-flight

Tags: ios, devops, xcrun, apple-developer-account

I've created a pipeline, which build the ipa file and upload it.
Here's the command to upload the ipa file to test-flight:

```
      upload_to_testflight:
        stage: upload_to_testflight
        image: alpine:latest  
        script:  
          - xcrun altool --upload-app -f ios/test.ipa -t ios -u $YOUR_APPLE_ID -p $YOUR_APP_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD --verbose
```

And the pipeline is throwing me this error:

```
2023-07-26 17:35:29.069 Verbose logging enabled.
2023-07-26 17:35:29.071 Will look for transporter at executable bundle relative path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
2023-07-26 17:35:29.071 Looking for Transporter at path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
2023-07-26 17:35:29.071 Looking for Transporter at path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
2023-07-26 17:35:29.071 Looking for Transporter at path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
2023-07-26 17:35:29.071 Looking for Transporter at path: /Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
2023-07-26 17:35:29.071 Looking for Transporter at path: /usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
2023-07-26 17:35:29.071 Using default transporter location: /usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
2023-07-26 17:35:29.071 iTMSTransporter is not available. Using REST APIs.
2023-07-26 17:35:30.184 
=======================
WEB SERVICE REQUEST 'generateAppleConnectToken'
           URL: https://contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZLabelService.woa/json/MZITunesSoftwareService
       timeout: 1800
        method: POST
   httpHeaders: {
    "Content-Length" = 510;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    "x-request-id" = "20230726173530-208";
    "x-tx-client-name" = altool;
    "x-tx-client-version" = "6.315 (14315)";
    "x-tx-method" = generateAppleConnectToken;
}
      httpBody: {
    id = "20230726173530-208";
    jsonrpc = "2.0";
    method = generateAppleConnectToken;
    params =     {
        Application = altool;
        ApplicationBundleId = "com.apple.itunes.altool";
        FrameworkVersions =         {
            "com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesConnectFoundation" = "6.315 (14315)";
            "com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesConnectFoundationExtras" = "6.315 (14315)";
            "com.apple.itunes.connect.ITunesPackage" = "6.315 (14315)";
        };
        OSIdentifier = "Mac OS X 13.0.0 (arm64)";
        Password = **hidden value**;
        Username = "test.com";
        Version = "6.315 (14315)";
    };
}
=======================
2023-07-26 17:35:31.175 
=======================
WEB SERVICE RESPONSE (generateAppleConnectToken):
 status code: 200 (no error)
   MIME/TYPE: application/json
 httpHeaders: {
    "Accept-Language" = "en-GB,en;q=0.9";
    "Cache-Control" = "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 281;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Wed, 26 Jul 2023 12:33:46 GMT";
    Expires = "Tue, 18-Jul-2023 23:32:42 GMT";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "daiquiri/3.0.0";
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
    "apple-originating-system" = MZContentDeliveryProducer;
    "apple-seq" = "0.0";
    "apple-timing-app" = "111 ms";
    "apple-tk" = false;
    b3 = "b51838aeb440546fc0becaaf683483d3-7fc0bcdaa03f7384";
    "x-apple-application-instance" = 240813;
    "x-apple-application-site" = MR22;
    "x-apple-jingle-correlation-key" = WUMDRLVUIBKG7QF6ZKXWQNED2M;
    "x-apple-request-uuid" = "b51838ae-b440-546f-c0be-caaf683483d3";
    "x-b3-spanid" = 7fc0bcdaa03f7384;
    "x-b3-traceid" = b51838aeb440546fc0becaaf683483d3;
    "x-daiquiri-instance" = "daiquiri:13624002:mr85p00it-hyhk03094901:7987:23RELEASE105:daiquiri-amp-processing-shared-int-001-mr, daiquiri:18493001:mr85p00it-hyhk03154801:7987:23RELEASE105:daiquiri-amp-all-shared-ext-001-mr";
    "x-json-content-length" = 700;
    "x-request-through-daiquiri-producer" = "mr-internal";
    "x-responding-instance" = "MZContentDeliveryProducer:240813:::";
    "x-webobjects-loadaverage" = 0;
}
    httpBody: {"result":{"Errors":["Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com (-22938)"],"EnableJWTForAllCalls":false,"RestartClient":false,"ErrorCode":-22938,"ErrorMessage":"Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com (-22938)","ShouldUseRESTAPIs":false,"Success":false},"id":"20230726173530-208","jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"message":"Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com (-22938)","code":-22938}}
=======================
2023-07-26 17:35:31.177 Web service call (generateAppleConnectToken) result: {
    EnableJWTForAllCalls = 0;
    ErrorCode = "-22938";
    ErrorMessage = "Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-spec\U2026";
    Errors =     (
        "Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-spec\U2026"
    );
    RestartClient = 0;
    ShouldUseRESTAPIs = 0;
    Success = 0;
}
2023-07-26 17:35:31.184 {
    EnableJWTForAllCalls = 0;
    ErrorCode = "-22938";
    ErrorMessage = "Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com (-22938)";
    Errors =     (
        "Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com (-22938)"
    );
    RestartClient = 0;
    ShouldUseRESTAPIs = 0;
    Success = 0;
}
2023-07-26 17:35:31.185 Non-localized server string received: 'Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com'.
2023-07-26 17:35:31.186 Non-localized server string received: 'Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com'.
2023-07-26 17:35:31.323 *** Error: Error uploading 'ios/Aqaar.ipa'.
2023-07-26 17:35:31.323 *** Error: Unable to upload archive. Failed to get authorization for username 'test.com' and password. (
    "Error Domain=ITunesConnectionOperationErrorDomain Code=-19000 \"Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com, NSLocalizedDescription=Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com, NSLocalizedFailureReason=App Store operation failed.}"
) (-1011)
 {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Unable to upload archive.";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Failed to get authorization for username 'test.com' and password. (\n    \"Error Domain=ITunesConnectionOperationErrorDomain Code=-19000 \\\"Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com\\\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com, NSLocalizedDescription=Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com, NSLocalizedFailureReason=App Store operation failed.}\"\n)";
}
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I've also tried it locally by export the build from xcode and tried to push the ipa to test-flight by this command and there i've provided the username and password in that command.
Like this:

```
    xcrun altool --upload-app -f test.ipa -u test.com -p abctest123
```

And its throwing me this error:

```
        2023-07-26 18:22:26.972 *** Error: Error uploading 'test.ipa'.
        2023-07-26 18:22:26.974 *** Error: Unable to upload archive. Failed to get authorization for username 'test.com' and password. (
            "Error Domain=ITunesConnectionOperationErrorDomain Code=-19000 \"Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com, NSLocalizedDescription=Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com, NSLocalizedFailureReason=App Store operation failed.}"
        ) (-1011)
        {
            NSLocalizedDescription = "Unable to upload archive.";
            NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Failed to get authorization for username 'test.com' and password. (\n    \"Error Domain=ITunesConnectionOperationErrorDomain Code=-19000 \\\"Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com\\\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com, NSLocalizedDescription=Sign in with the app-specific password you generated. If you forgot the app-specific password or need to create a new one, go to appleid.apple.com, NSLocalizedFailureReason=App Store operation failed.}\"\n)";
        }
```

I've created App specific password by this process:
go to https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage and in the **Security** section, click **App-Specific Passwords** and create new one.
Also, Two-factor authentication is enabled in the account.

I need help to understand this why its not authorising.

I'm trying to upload the ipa but showing the above error.